# How to make WebStorm automatically add new line and paste left indentation for braces

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, ide, webstorm, eslint

I want to make WebStorm doing following action:

1) I'm writing new property within JS object which is an object literal:

```
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: {|} <-- caret is here and then I press Enter button
}
```

2) then I press Enter and expect to see following picture:

```
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: {
    |  <-- caret should be here
  }
}
```

Now I'm getting this result:

```
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: {
  |}  <-- caret is here
}
```

and also would be cool to make it adding two spaces inside an empty JS literal object right after closing the brace

```
{ | } <-- caret here right after closing the brace
```

Comment: What do you get when you press enter? On my machine pressing Enter results in expected behavior.

Comment: updated @y.bedrov

Comment: I also can't reproduce your issue, and I was trying for a while. What happens if you go to `Settings - Editor - Code Style` and choose `Scheme: Default IDE`? I think IntelliJ by default has your expected behavior, perhaps you've overrode that?

Comment: I've tried it, doesn't help @petre

Comment: May be this is because I've applied new color theme for IDE, but I'm not sure, because it's only for colors

Comment: Please post screenshot of your `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Smart Keys` screen.

Comment: Oh thanks, there was not checked "Smart indent"  in Settings -> Editor -> General -> Smart Keys

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution: 
go to  Settings -> Editor -> General -> Smart Keys 
and turn on checkbox 'Smart indent'